# How to remove GPIO ribbon from raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, ribbon-cable

This is basically it. I got my new raspberry pi and I got a GPIO ribbon to connect it from the raspberry's GPIO's to a breadboard. Now I am trying to remove the ribbon from the raspberry by just pulling upwards, but despite the great amount of force I've used, it does not come out.

[image]

How do I get the ribbon out of the pins?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you show us a picture?

Comment: I posted the picture. Do you have any idea of how I can remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull harder.  Assuming it is a standard double row IDC connector, anyway.  These things sometimes require a lot of force to separate due to the number of pins.  You can also try working it off by rocking it back and forth, only moving each end by 1-2 mm to avoid bending the pins.

Comment: Also, "rock" the connector - try to raise one end a small amount, then raise the other end, etc... until it is fully released (but don't rock the connector enough to bend the pins!)

Comment: Thank you... I just needed to pull harder indeed. I bent 2 pins in the process though. Never using that stupid thing again. I'd rather use jumper cables. Thank you again!

Comment: Levering it up with a small flat-blade screwdriver works well too. (obviously) you have to make sure the circuit is off to avoid accidental shorts.

Comment: Yes, best to remove the board from the case, then insert a the screwdriver between the header plastic and the connector plastic at one end. Rotate the screwdriver slightly. Then go to the other end and do the same.  Repeat a couple times and then connector will be loose enough for you to pull it off with no bent pins.